# Remove users' accept rates from the API

Tags: feature-request, users, api-v2.3

The accept rate of users [isn't shown on the site since more than 6-8 years](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164654/295232). Nevertheless, it's [still returned by default on most calls returning user details](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/shallow-user). It doesn't serve any purpose anymore, and it will save a few fractions of a percent of bandwidth/CPU usage/CO<sub>2</sub> production.